# NSTextField / NSSearchField default value that is removed when focus is on the field

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nssearchfield

I would like to have a default value for a `NSTextField` (or `NSSearchField`) and have this default value removed when the user clicks on it and set back when the text view loses the focus and the text field is empty. Like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/T03vE]

It sounds like I should extend `NSSearchField` but I was wondering if there was an easier solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This functionality is in fact built-in; there's no need to subclass or otherwise extend `NSSearchField`.

That's the field's [placeholder string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SearchFields/Articles/AddingSearchField.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002244-BABFIBIA). You can set it either in IB or via a call to [`setPlaceholderString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextFieldCell/setPlaceholderString%3a). Notice that this is a method of `NSTextFieldCell`. An `NSTextField` is the "public face" of its cell, and has cover methods for almost all of the cell's functionality. In this case, however, you need to send the message directly to the cell:

```
[[field cell] setPlaceholderString:@"Jumbo jets"];
```

Since `NSSearchField` and `NSSearchFieldCell` inherit from `NSTextField` and `NSTextFieldCell`, respectively, the process is the same for them.

Answer (score 2):

Set the place holder string on the NSTextFields's NSTextFieldCell using

`[[textField cell] setPlaceholderString:@"String Matching"];`